# Can I have two or more WebMatrix sites running at once?

Tags: webmatrix, iis-express

I'm using WebMatrix2 to run some test sites locally on my box.  Each site of course is given its own port number by WM2 (eg localhost:15632 or localhost:12643)

What I haven't figured out is how to run two of those WebMatrix (I suppose they're actually IIS Express sites under the hood) at the same time, so I don't have to go back to the WM interface and choose a site to open.  Since these sites each run under a different port can I not run them simultaneously?  Or is this a limitation of IIS Express?

Comment: You can run multiple sites under IIS Express either by starting them from the command line (`iisexpress /site:mySite`) or by opening multiple instances of WebMatrix.

Comment: Ah - now that your question has been reopened, I have answered more fully below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run multiple sites under IIS Express by starting them from the command line. Navigate to the directory containing iisexpress.exe (usually C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express) then use the following command where mySite represents the site to start:

```
iisexpress /site:mySite
```

or you can simply open multiple instances of WebMatrix.

Once you have opened your sites, you can manage them from the Notifications area on your task bar.

Here's more about running IIS Express from the command line: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

Comment: @larryq This is the method I use on my box, but it may help to remind anyone reading this answer that a simple batch file in the startup folder (givent this command) will ensure that your site starts every time you boot up the machine. That's what I do.